# Laplacian and Dirac function gives contradictory result.

Tags: dirac-delta

The following equation is correct for all non-negative real numbers:

$$4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})=\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^{3}},$$
$$r\in[0,+\infty)$$

especially, when r=0, both sides give infinity.

However, the right handside can further give:

$$\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^{3}}=\frac{\nabla\cdot\mathbf{r}}{r^{3}}+\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{r^{3}}=\frac{3}{r^{3}}-\frac{3}{r^{3}}=0$$

which is very strange, since $$4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})=0,$$

I have read the proof for $r\neq0$ at [Laplacians and Dirac delta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/laplacians-and-dirac-delta-functions)[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/laplacians-and-dirac-delta-functions), but there, this issue is not addressed.

Can anyone explain what happens here?

Comment: The equality holds in the sense of distributions. This is not an equality of functions. Note that $\frac{{\bf{r}}}{r^{3}}$ is not even defined at $r = 0$, so it cannot be differentiable at this point. Thus, your conclusion $\nabla \cdot \frac{{\bf{r}}}{r^{3}}=0$ holds if $r\neq 0$.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514339/2451

Comment: Related : [Divergence of  r^r2  , what is the 'paradox'?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488220/divergence-of-frac-hat-bf-rr2-what-is-the-paradox/488237#488237)