# $\left(\nabla^2\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=(-4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{x}))e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am studying the following calculation: 
\begin{align}
\int d^3\mathbf{x}\frac{1}{|{\mathbf{x}}|}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}} & = \frac{-1}{|\mathbf{q}|^2}\int d^3\mathbf{x}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\nabla^2\left(e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)= \\ 
&= \frac{-1}{|\mathbf{q}|^2}\int d^3\mathbf{x}\left(\nabla^2\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\\
&=\frac{-1}{|\mathbf{q}|^2}\int d^3\mathbf{x}\left(-4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{x})\right)e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}} = \\
&= \frac{4\pi}{|\mathbf{q}|^2}
\end{align}
I don't understand the following two equalities by what they are justified, there is some intermediate step?
$$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\nabla^2\left(e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)=\left(\nabla^2\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$$
$$\left(\nabla^2\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=(-4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{x}))e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$$

Comment: By "\abs{$\cdot$}", do you mean "$|\cdot |$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation $\int d^3x\frac{1}{|x|}\nabla^2e^{-iq\cdot x}=\int d^3x\left(\nabla^2\frac{1}{|x|}\right)e^{-iq\cdot x}$ uses integrration by parts twice, not the first identity you've conjectured, which is false. Your second conjectured equation is correct (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/laplacians-and-dirac-delta-functions)).