Verify Ampere's law using Biot- Savart equation
how can I verify Ampere's law using Biot- Savart equation on a circular current:

namely, to prove:
$$\oint\limits_{W}B\,\mathrm{d}w=\mu_0 I$$
what is the curve W we should integrate with?

Ampere's law applies to all closed curves, not just one in particular. So proving it by checking one specific curve $W$ is a nonstarter. (In principle one can switch to the differential form of Ampere's law $\nabla\times \vec{B}=\mu_0 \vec{J}$ and show that the curl of $\vec{B}$ vanishes except at the wire. But that requires knowing the B-field everywhere, not just along the axis, and thus is not terribly practical.)

@Semiclassical I thought about the differential form but normally for a filiform wire there's no such as a current density, there's just $I$ so I think it has to be integral form. Maybe you could argue the density might be expressable using Dirac delta functions.

@Conreu You can indeed express $\vec{J}$ in that scenario in terms of Dirac delta functions, the same as you could for either the divergence of a point charge's E-field or the curl of an infinite line current. (See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710553/what-is-the-current-density-of-a-circular-current for specifics in this particular case.) But admittedly this is not a calculation I'd be willing to do myself.

@Semiclassical understand that Ampere's law applies to any closed curves. But is there one such curve that can be used to verify the law easily?

You can pick a curve to test it, sure. But that will not be a proof, any more than by picking some polynomial and fully factoring it is a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Assuming the filament is in magnetostatic conditions, Ampère's law reads
$$\oint_{\mathrm W}\,\mathbf B\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w=\mu_0 I_{\text{enc}}$$
where $\mathrm d\boldsymbol w$ is tangent to the curve $\mathrm W$.
Let's then prove how Biot-Savart's law satisfies Ampère's law for any curve:
Substituting Biot-Savart's law we get that
$$\oint_{\mathrm W}\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\times(\boldsymbol{r-r'})}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|^3}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w=4\pi$$
has to hold. Let's compute that integral. First we'll employ
$$\boldsymbol\nabla\times\left(\dfrac{\mathbf a}{\phi}\right)=\boldsymbol\nabla\dfrac{1}{\phi}\times\mathbf a+\dfrac{1}{\phi}\boldsymbol\nabla\times\mathbf a$$
where we identify $\mathbf a=\mathrm d\boldsymbol \ell$ and $\phi=|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|$. Hence, since $\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell$ only depends on $\boldsymbol r'$,
$$\oint_{\mathrm W}\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\times(\boldsymbol{r-r'})}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|^3}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w=\oint_{\mathrm W}\boldsymbol\nabla\times\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w$$
Using Stokes' theorem, the integral becomes
$$\iint_{S_\mathrm W}\boldsymbol\nabla\times\boldsymbol\nabla\times\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol S_\mathrm W$$
where
$$\boldsymbol\nabla\times\boldsymbol\nabla\times\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}=\boldsymbol\nabla\left(\oint_C\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}\right)-\boldsymbol\nabla^2\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}$$
but
$$\oint_C\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}=-\oint_C\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla'\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}=-\oint_C \mathrm d\left(\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}\right)=0$$
and so the first term vanishes. Moreover,
$$\boldsymbol\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}=4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\boldsymbol{r-r'}),$$
and thus, the original integral reduces to
$$\begin{aligned}
&\oint_{\mathrm W}\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\times(\boldsymbol{r-r'})}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|^3}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w\\
&=-4\pi\iint_{S_{\mathrm W}}\oint_C \delta^{(3)}(\boldsymbol{r-r'})\,\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\,\mathrm d\boldsymbol S_{\mathrm W}\\
&=-4\pi\iint_{S_{\mathrm W}}[\delta(y-y')\delta(z-z')\boldsymbol i+\delta(x-x')\delta(z-z')\boldsymbol j+\delta(x-x')\delta(y-y')\boldsymbol k]\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol S_{\mathrm W}=4\pi\,\blacksquare
\end{aligned}$$

One point here: the double-loop integral is Gauss's linking integral, and as such should count the number of times the curve $W$ links with the curve $C$. That this comes out as linking number $1$ in this case is presumably implicit in how $S_W$ is defined in the case of a single-linking, but that's not an altogether trivial point to pass over. (It might be better to frame the second-to-last integral as counting the number of times that the contour $C$ "pierces" $S_W$.)

How to understand this is what we need to prove: $$\oint_{\mathrm W}\oint_C\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\times(\boldsymbol{r-r'})}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|^3}\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol w=4\pi$$

Where can I find the relationship between Laplacian and Dirac's delta function: $$\boldsymbol\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}=4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\boldsymbol{r-r'})$$

Biot-Savart law is
$$\mathbf B=\dfrac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\oint_C \dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\ell\times(\boldsymbol{r-r'})}{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}|}$$
if you substitute this in Ampère's law you'll be able to cancel out the $\mu_0$ and $I$ on both sides and isolate the $4\pi$ to the other side.
As for the Dirac delta relationship you sould address to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/where-does-the-relation-nabla21-r-4-pi-delta3-bf-r-between-laplacian

I proved it for the general case because, as they said in the comment section above, it is really difficult to compute analytically these integrals even for $\mathrm W$ curves as simple as circles or squares.

I'm still trying to figure out an alternative to this proof because I think I made some mistakes and it might contain some flaws...
